# I want names returned instead id

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and I want to join it.

Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20410/2

In the columns: segunda, terca, quarta, quinta and sexta
instead of numbers... I need the names in "materias" table.
But I check all the ID's from the same table "materias"

Is that possible? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two ways using inner joins and using sub queries.

Using Inner Join:

```
SELECT
h.id_classe,
h.id_aula,
s.serie,
m1.materia as segunda,
m2.materia as terca,
m3.materia as quarta,
m4.materia as quinta,
m5.materia as sexta
FROM horario_de_aulas h
INNER JOIN materias as m1 on h.segunda = m1.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m2 on h.terca = m2.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m3 on h.quarta = m3.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m4 on h.quinta = m4.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m5 on h.sexta = m5.id_materia
INNER JOIN series s ON h.classe = s.id_serie = 1
LIMIT 4
```

Using Sub Query

```
SELECT
h.id_classe,
h.id_aula,
s.serie,
(select materia from materias where id_materia=h.segunda) as segunda,
(select materia from materias where id_materia=h.terca) as terca,
(select materia from materias where id_materia=h.quarta) as quarta,
(select materia from materias where id_materia=h.quinta) as quinta,
(select materia from materias where id_materia=h.sexta) as sexta
FROM horario_de_aulas h
INNER JOIN materias m
INNER JOIN series s ON h.classe = s.id_serie = 1
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
h.id_classe,
h.id_aula,
s.serie,
m1.materia as segunda,
m2.materia as terca,
m3.materia as quarta,
m4.materia as quinta,
m5.materia as sexta
FROM horario_de_aulas h
INNER JOIN materias as m1 on h.segunda = m1.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m2 on h.terca = m2.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m3 on h.quarta = m3.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m4 on h.quinta = m4.id_materia
INNER JOIN materias as m5 on h.sexta = m5.id_materia
INNER JOIN series s ON h.classe = s.id_serie = 1
LIMIT 4
```